# X-Accel-Redirect to a soft-linked directory gives 403 permission denied

Tags: django, nginx

We have a django view that returns a response with the X-Accel-Redirect header:

```
@login_required
def get_secure_file(request):
    response = HttpResponse()
    # Content-type will be detected by nginx
    del response['Content-Type']
    response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/securemedia/signicat/foo.pdf'
    return response
```

and the nginx config is set up with:

```
    location /securemedia/ {
        internal;
        alias /srv/data/smedia/mysite/filer_private/;
    }
```

in `/srv/data/smedia/mysite/filer_private/` there is a (soft) link to `/srv/data/appdata/signicat/` with the following permissions/owners/groups:

```
/srv$ ls -ld /srv/data/appdata/sig*
drwxrwsr-x 3 erlend gunicorn 86016 Apr 14 16:00 /srv/data/appdata/signicat

/srv$ ls -ld /srv/data/smedia/mysite/filer_private/sig*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sak www-data   26 Apr  3 15:26 /srv/data/smedia/mysite/filer_private/signicat -> /srv/data/appdata/signicat
```

and the file we're looking for is inside the signicat directory:

```
/srv$ ls -l /srv/data/appdata/signicat/foo*
-rw-rw-r-- 2 sak gunicorn 281376 Apr 14 15:19 /srv/data/appdata/signicat/foo.pdf
```

i.e. everything should at least be world-readable.

Still we get a 403 error from nginx, access.log:

```
88.88.88.88 - - [14/Apr/2023:15:31:30 +0200] "GET /get-secure-file/ HTTP/1.1" 403 196 0.066 "https : //www.mysite.com/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "http-host=www.mysite.com" "elapsed=0.066s" "scheme=https"
```

error.log:

```
2023/04/14 15:31:20 [error] 1460872#1460872: *785119 open() "/srv/data/smedia/mysite/filer_private/signicat/foo.pdf" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 99.99.99.99, server: www.mysite.com, request: "GET /get-secure-file/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/gunicorn@mysite.sock/get-secure-file/", host: "www.mysite.com", referrer: "https : //www.mysite.com/dashboard/"
```

(space added around colons since url's, even fictitious ones, can't exist in question text..)

Copying the `foo.pdf` file (or creating a hard link) to `/srv/data/smedia/mysite/filer_private/` (and modifying the `X-Accel-Redirect` header) works.

Creating a subdirectory `filer_private/sig2` and copying the file into it also works.

Creating a soft link from `filer_private/sig2` to `filer_private/sig3` also works.

The only thing that doesn't work is the link from `filer_private/signicat -> /srv/data/appdata/signicat`

Is there a rule about files needing to be "physically" below the directory declared in the nginx `alias` directive, or is there a permission missing..?

Comment: Have you checked the ownership of the directories and put them all in the scope of nginx i.e www-data